# java factory.terminals doesn't return creator cardreader in it's list

Tags: java, terminal, smartcard

I want to work with smart card using javax.smartcardio .
The problem is that my creator card Reader is not detected.
Here is the function I call :

```
 public static List<CardTerminal> getTerminals() throws Exception{
     javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
     List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
     return terminals;
}
```

the list "terminals" is null . 
my card reader is connected using a serial to usb converter and is detected by it's own sdk code on port COM5.
Thanks.

Comment: Does your card reader support PC/SC?

Comment: I don't know. PC/SC is not mentioned anywhere in the cardreader's documentation.

Comment: Well, if your reader does not support PC/SC, it won't be accessible through a PC/SC API (i.e. Java Smart Card IO).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try to learn more about my card reader capabilities.

Comment: @MichaelRoland My Card Reader is now accesible through PC/SC's **pcscd**  service but still can't get llist from above program. Could you guide to get list--- 

**java -Djava.library.path=java/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64 -Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=usr/lib/libpcsclite.so**

My Card Reader is ACR122U